# List Index out of Range for Python Function when Computing Projectile Motion

Tags: python, index-error

I am having some trouble writing some python code regarding projectile motion and have come across this hour and am unsure of how to fix it. I am a bit of a python amateur, so please bare with my lack of knowledge. The error occurs in

```
vx.append(vx[counter]+dt*ax[counter])
```

, but I assume it will also carry on for the lines beneath.The error I receive reads "IndexError: list index out of range".

The task at hand is to create a function that computes the trajectory of a discus whilst including lift and drag and then plot it on a set of axis. The code is written below:

```
 import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sin, cos, pi, sqrt

# Variables 

M = 1.0 # Mass of discus in kg
g = 9.81 # Acceleration due to gravity (m/s^2)
V = 30 # Initial velocity in m/s
ang = 30 # Angle of initial velocity in degrees
Cd = 0.54 # Drag coefficient
Cl = 0.87 #Lift coefficient 
dt = 0.01 # time step in s
t = [0] # start time
vx = [V*np.cos(ang/180*pi)] # velocity in x direction upon release
vy = [V*np.sin(ang/180*pi)] # velocity in y direction upon release
x = [0] # original x position
y = [1.8] # original y position
rho = 1.2 #density in kg/m^3
a_ref = 0.025 #area in m^2
gamma = 35/180*np.pi #flight path angle



def abs_velocity (vx, vy):
    return sqrt(((vx)**2)+((vy)**2))
def gamma(c_l, c_d):
    return (f_d/f_l)

def ax(rho, V, a_ref, M , Cl, gamma, Cd, g):
    V = abs_velocity(vx, vy)
    return [((rho*V**2*a_ref)/(2*M))*(Cl *sin(gamma) - Cd * cos(gamma))]    

def ay (rho, V, a_ref, M , Cl, gamma, Cd, g):
    V = abs_velocity(vx, vy)
    return [((rho*V**2*a_ref)/(2*M))*(Cl* np.cos(gamma) - Cd* np.sin(gamma)) -g]
def vx (V, ax, dt):
    return (V +ax*dt)

def vy (V, ay, dt):
    V = abs_velocity(vx, vy)
    return (V + ay*dt)

def f_l(rho, V, a_ref, Cl):
    V = abs_velocity(vx, vy)
    return (0.5 * rho * V**2 * a_ref * Cl)

def f_d(rho, v, a_ref, Cd):
    V = abs_velocity(vx, vy)
    return (0.5 * rho * V**2 * a_ref * Cd)

#  Lists for results
x = []
y = []
vx = []
vy = []

counter = 0

while (y[counter] >= 0):
    t.append(t[counter]+dt)
    
    #Update Velocity
    vx.append(vx[counter]+dt*ax[counter])
    vy.append(vy[counter]+dt*ay[counter])
    
    #Update x and y position
    
    x.append(x[counter]+dt*vx[counter] + 0.5*ax[counter]*dt**2)
    y.append(y[counter]+dt*vy[counter] + 0.5*ay[counter]*dt**2)
    
    abs_velocity = np.sqrt(vx[counter+1]**2 + vy[counter+1]**2)
    
    #drag = 0.5 * rho * V**2 * a_ref * Cd
    #lift = 0.5 * rho * V**2 * a_ref * Cl
    
    ax.append(((rho*V**2*a_ref)/(2*M))*(Cl *sin(gamma) - Cd * cos(gamma)))
    ay.append(((rho*V**2*a_ref)/(2*M))*(Cl* cos(gamma) - Cd* sin(gamma)) -g)
    counter = counter +1

plt.plot(x,y,'ro')
plt.title("Womens Discus!")
plt.ylabel("y (m)")
plt.xlabel("x (m)")

print ("Discus Throw is equal to {:3.1f} m".format(x[counter]))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. TIA very much!

Comment: Sounds like a great time to pull out your visual debugger and start stepping through your code to see what it's doing and figure out what's going wrong.  This isn't a forum for other people to debug your code for you if you haven't tried at all yourself.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  You posted 75 lines of code to exhibit a 10-line problem.  You haven't yet traced the offending values.  Add a `print` statement or two to do that.

Comment: @Steve: actually, it *is* such a forum, but only after the poster has done the expected initial work to trace and isolate the problem.

Comment: @Prune, I kinda-sorta getcha.  I ammended my comment.

Comment: In your code, you do this first `y = [1.8] # original y position` then you have all your functions defined and then you are resetting `y = []` The very next thing you are doing is checking in the while loop if `y[counter] >= 0`. Do you think y has anything inside?

Comment: it is the same for velocity as well. All your variables you reset can cause you problems.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are defining the values for some of your key variables at the beginning of the code.

```
vx = [V*np.cos(ang/180*pi)] # velocity in x direction upon release
vy = [V*np.sin(ang/180*pi)] # velocity in y direction upon release
x = [0] # original x position
y = [1.8] # original y position
```

Later you have your functions defined. Then you are resetting the values for these critical variables.

```
#  Lists for results
x = []
y = []
vx = []
vy = []
```

Then you are trying to reference the lists but there isn't anything in it to reference.

```
counter = 0

while (y[counter] >= 0):
    t.append(t[counter]+dt)
    
    #Update Velocity
    vx.append(vx[counter]+dt*ax[counter])
    vy.append(vy[counter]+dt*ay[counter])
```

The while loop will fail as y[0] does not exist.

Here's how your code will try to execute. As you can see, it throws an error.

The recommendation would be to comment out the lines of code where you reset values for x, y, vx, vy

```
>>> y = []
>>> while y[0] >=0:
    print ('got in')
    break

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    while y[0] >=0:
IndexError: list index out of range
```